# Is it safely to use nmealib on MCU?

Tags: c, stm32, nmea

I'm wondering if i could use nmealib (http://nmea.sourceforge.net/) on STM32. Library uses dynamic memory allocation through bget, is it applicable on embedded devices? Maybe someone used it on ARM (without OS)? Then how about memory leakages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedded devices can do dynamic memory allocation with no problem. The question you should really be asking is how much memory it uses, both code and RAM (in the form of initialized and uninitialized variables, stack and the heap). Many libraries not explicitly made for use in embedded systems aren't as conscious of resource usage. And of course, since an embedded application may run for months or years without a reset, even the most occasional memory leak will eventually become a problem.

Comment: >"even the most occasional memory leak will eventually become a problem".  

Well, this is the key problem, because after some investigations of nmea parsers i've got a conclusion that fully functional library (i mean nmealib) EXISTS but there is a risk of unstable work on embedded platform. Seems like i have to write my own library, at least i tried =)

Comment: Have you even tried using it? Do you have a reason to presume it will have a memory leak? If it did, it's open source, you could just track down the leak and fix it. Certainly it's less work than writing your own library.

Comment: nmealib is pretty big library, ImHO it's very risky to take library that could possibly work wrong, apply on it a few patches and sell that to somebody. Currently i'm writing my own library from zero with static memory allocation and by now it seems like a nice solution. Btw IAR compiler doesn't want to manage with BGET library as is =)

Comment: Embedded devices without MMUs, like the stm32, can face fragmentation problems when allocating and deleting memory blocks of random sizes.